# How to replace @Rule annotation in JUnit 5 on TextReport and BrowserWebDriverContainer?

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4, junit5

I'm trying to migration from **JUnit4** to **JUnit5** and I have a `@Rule` annotation and I don't exactly know how I can replace this. I tried `@ExtendWith` but not working for me.

My code with **JUnit 4** annotations:

```java
    @Rule
    public TextReport textReport = new TextReport();

    @Rule
    public BrowserWebDriverContainer chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer()
            .withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions());
```

Edit:
The part of my current code is:

```
@Testcontainers
@ExtendWith(TextReportExtension.class)
public class TestBase {

    @Container
    public static BrowserWebDriverContainer chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer()
            .withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions());

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RemoteWebDriver driver = chrome.getWebDriver();
        System.out.println("VNC Address: " + chrome.getVncAddress());
```

All test classes extends TestBase.
And I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
```

Comment: I've updated my answer and I guess the error comes from mixing JUnit 4 & 5 in the same test.

Comment: can you post TextReportExtension.class

Answer (score 1):

Testcontainers offers JUnit 5 support by adding the following dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>1.14.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This allows you to refactor `BrowserWebDriverContainer` to the following:

```
@Testcontainers
public class YourTest {

  @Container
  public static BrowserWebDriverContainer chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer()
            .withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions());

}
```

For the `TextReport` rule, simply add the following extension from selenide to your class and it will capture the console for you:

```
@Testcontainers
@ExtendWith(TextReportExtension.class)
public class YourTest {

}
```

**UPDATE**: Make sure to always either use JUnit 4 or JUnit 5 in your test. `@Before` is from JUnit 4, try to replace it with `@BeforeEach` and ensure your `@Test` is coming from `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`.